# MongoDB count with queries

Tags: mongodb

I've been working on a project that now needs to use the MongoDB count function (MySQL equivalent's count function). The code I have at the moment is

```
$filter = ["username" => array('$ne' => null, '$ne' => '')];

$options = ["projection" => ['username' => true]];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);

$cursor = $mongo->executeQuery('mongodbLog.logs', $query);
```

I want to add the count functionality in the $filter array, but I can't get it to work correctly.

I want my MongoDB query to get the same result as this MySQL query: "`SELECT username,count(*) FROM mysqlLog WHERE username <> '' GROUP BY username`".
All I have managed so far is the where clause equivalent and now I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you think `array('$ne' => null, '$ne' => '')` returns?

Comment: This returns all fields where the column username is not null or an empty string.

Comment: Not quite what I was asking. http://ideone.com/vBkUgj

Comment: Oh sorry! I'm not sure what you mean. I am very new to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

Aggregation Stages - `$match` - `$group` - `$project`

```
 $pipeline = 
        [
            [   
                '$match' => 
                    [   
                    '$and' => 
                        [
                             ['username' => ['$ne' => null]], 
                             ['username' => ['$ne' => '']],
                        ],
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$group' => 
                    [
                      '_id' => '$username',
                      'count' => ['$sum' => 1],
                    ],
            ],
            [
                '$project' => 
                    [
                      '_id' => 0,
                      'username' => 1,
                      'count' => 1,
                    ],
            ],
        ];

    $command = new \MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'aggregate' => 'logs', 
        'pipeline' => $pipeline
        ]);

    $cursor = $mongo->executeCommand('mongodbLog', $command);
```

Comment: Hey, that seems to do the trick! Didnt give me the username at first but I removed the '_id' => 0 since I noticed the username was put there. Thanks for your help! Any idea how I would include searching within a given timestamp too? I have used the code "timestamp" => array('$gte' => intval($startDate) earlier, but not sure where to put it in this structure.

Edit: I put "['timestamp' => ['$gte' => intval($startDate)]]," after the username conditions. Thank you very much for your help.